# List of WMI Method Attributes

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmic

I try to access all attributes of the given method from any classes into the WMI.

For example, I can list the methods inside "Win32_SystemDriver " class

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemDriver -List | Select -ExpandProperty Methods

Name               InParameters                           OutParameters                          Origin            Qualifiers
----               ------------                           -------------                          ------            ----------
StartService                                              System.Management.ManagementBaseObject CIM_Service       {MappingStrings, Override, ValueMap}
StopService                                               System.Management.ManagementBaseObject CIM_Service       {MappingStrings, Override, ValueMap}
PauseService                                              System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Win32_BaseService {MappingStrings, ValueMap}
ResumeService                                             System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Win32_BaseService {MappingStrings, ValueMap}
InterrogateService                                        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Win32_BaseService {MappingStrings, ValueMap}
UserControlService System.Management.ManagementBaseObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Win32_BaseService {MappingStrings, ValueMap}
Create             System.Management.ManagementBaseObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Win32_BaseService {MappingStrings, Static, ValueMap}
Change             System.Management.ManagementBaseObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Win32_BaseService {MappingStrings, ValueMap}
ChangeStartMode    System.Management.ManagementBaseObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Win32_BaseService {MappingStrings, ValueMap}
Delete                                                    System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Win32_BaseService {MappingStrings, ValueMap}
```

[In MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/create-method-in-class-win32-systemdriver), Create method of the Win32_SystemDriver class has many attributes like;

```
uint32 Create(
  [in] string  Name,
  [in] string  DisplayName,
  [in] string  PathName,
  [in] uint8   ServiceType,
  [in] uint8   ErrorControl,
  [in] string  StartMode,
  [in] boolean DesktopInteract,
  [in] string  StartName,
  [in] string  StartPassword,
  [in] string  LoadOrderGroup,
  [in] string  LoadOrderGroupDependencies[],
  [in] string  ServiceDependencies[]
);
```

Can I see these properties with CIM/WMI cmdlets? Also, if it is possible I want to see with their descriptions.

Comment: `(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemDriver -List | Get-Member -MemberType Method|% definition) -replace '^.+\(|\)$' -split ',\s?'`

Comment: `switch -regex ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemDriver -List | Get-Member -MemberType Method|% definition) -replace '^.+\(|\)$'  -split ',\s?'){'^(?<Type>\S+)\s+(?<Name>.+)$'{$matches.Remove(0);[PSCustomObject]$matches}}`

Comment: `(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemDriver -List | Get-Member -MemberType Method|% definition) -replace '^.+\(|\)$' -split ',\s?' | % {, -split $_ |% {[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$_[1];Type=$_[0]}}} `

Comment: I realized that, for instance can u try "win32_process" class? can we made it a recursive way, because inside this class have another class's properties etc @DougMaurer

Comment: The only class I see in there is ProcessStartup which has no methods. You have another example where a child class has methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call "attributes" are parameters that are passed to the `Create()` method. Those parameters are displayed in the `Definition` property of the `Create()` member if you run `Get-Member`:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemDriver -List | Get-Member Create | Format-List

TypeName   : System.Management.ManagementClass#ROOT\cimv2\Win32_SystemDriver
Name       : Create
MemberType : Method
Definition : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Create(System.String Name, System.String DisplayName,
             System.String PathName, System.Byte ServiceType, System.Byte ErrorControl, System.String StartMode,
             System.Boolean DesktopInteract, System.String StartName, System.String StartPassword, System.String
             LoadOrderGroup, System.String[] LoadOrderGroupDependencies, System.String[] ServiceDependencies
```

If you want it as a list we can use Doug's Regex pattern:

```
PS > (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemDriver -List | Get-Member Create).Definition -replace '^.+\(|\)$' -split ',\s?'

System.String Name
System.String DisplayName
System.String PathName
System.Byte ServiceType
System.Byte ErrorControl
System.String StartMode
System.Boolean DesktopInteract
System.String StartName
System.String StartPassword
System.String LoadOrderGroup
System.String[] LoadOrderGroupDependencies
System.String[] ServiceDependencies
```

With some more parsing we can turn these into more readable/usable objects:

```
PS > (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemDriver -List | Get-Member Create).Definition -replace '^.+\(|\)$' -split ',\s?' | ForEach-Object {
   $split = $_.Split()
   [PSCustomObject]@{
      Parameter = $split[1]
      Type = [type]$split[0]
   }
}

Parameter                  Type
---------                  ----
Name                       System.String
DisplayName                System.String
PathName                   System.String
ServiceType                System.Byte
ErrorControl               System.Byte
StartMode                  System.String
DesktopInteract            System.Boolean
StartName                  System.String
StartPassword              System.String
LoadOrderGroup             System.String
LoadOrderGroupDependencies System.String[]
ServiceDependencies        System.String[]
```

We also converted the `Type` strings to `[System.Type]` objects.

Comment: thank u for expanding Doug's answer